# google adwords api: how to get adgroupId in Keyword/Ad?

Tags: google-ads-api

Based on code examples on google website I am able to fetch keywords and ads. The example prints something like this:

```
 printf("Text ad with headline '%s' and id '%s' was found.\n", $googleAd->ad->headline, $googleAd->ad->id);
```

based on such field list which was fetched:

```
 $selector->fields = array('Headline', 'Id')
```

Is it possible to get adGroupId as well ? I have been looking at [documentation for TextAd](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/AdGroupAdService.TextAd.html), however I cannot see adGroupId in field list. I am afraid it is not possible, because [adgroup](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/AdGroupService.AdGroup.html) has field called campaignId. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get adgroup id. It is part of AdGroupAd type, and can be retrieved using "AdGroupId" as selector name. Then you would retrieve the field as $googleAd->adGroupId. More details here:

http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/AdGroupAdService.AdGroupAd.html

In the future, I recommend that you ask the questions on the official AdWords API forum at http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/community/. The forum is pretty active, and AdWords API team members regularly answer developer questions on the forum.

Comment: thanks i have found it already few days ago but the answer is valid so i accept it